# How do i rewrite url using urlrewrite in RestExpress

Tags: java, netty, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a small [REST-api](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress) using port

> {ip}:8081/{crud-operations-name}

and I have a website that points to this address but the problem is i still have to put port :

> 8081

all the time.

Actually I could just set my Java server to run on port :

> 80

, but that would lead to update all my clients(mobiles app) to listen on port 80 not on 8081 (Am i correct that all http request defaults to port 80?Correct me if im wrong). So I guess a better way is to rewrite the url when it comes to the Rest-Server of mine.

What I would want is like the behavior of htaccess hiding the port, Is it possible in urlrewrite using RestExpress?

Comment: Is your end goal to avoid having your users needing to type in the `8081` port in the address?

Comment: yes, avoid and security measures also

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think your answer was correct with minor adjustments, but you deleted it. Can you again post?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a port redirect to your Tomcat's `server.xml` file.  You can invite your users to access the site without specifying a port number, meaning that everyone will hit the default port `8080`.  When anyone accesses using port `8080`, the request will be redirected to `8081` which port presumably has some security settings associated with it.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     connectionTimeout="20000"
     URIEncoding="UTF-8"
     enableLookups="false"
     redirectPort="8081" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 servers? 1 for rerouting and the other is the rest-api? I'm actually using NettyServer

Comment: You should have mentioned what server you are using.